# Django - display the right variable

Tags: python, django

**My Goal:**

If the user has score > 1 display only the jobs that have the correlated category. So, if category.1 (name of the quiz) is DataScience, shows only the jobs that are about Data Science.

---

**What my result is:**

If the score > 1 it displays all the job offers present on the database. (as in picture)

---

What am I doing wrong? Any suggestions?

[image: user profile page]

quiz/models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Questions(models.Model):
    CAT_CHOICES = (
    ('datascience', 'DataScience'),
    ('productowner', 'ProductOwner'),
    ('businessanalyst', 'BusinessAnalyst'),
    #('sports','Sports'),
    #('movies','Movies'),
    #('maths','Maths'),
    #('generalknowledge','GeneralKnowledge'),


)
    question = models.CharField(max_length = 250)
    optiona = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    optionb = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    optionc = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    optiond = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    answer = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    catagory = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices = CAT_CHOICES)
    student = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-catagory',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question
```

jobs/models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


# Create your models here.
class post_job(models.Model):

    posizione= models.CharField(max_length=20)
    descrizione= models.TextField(max_length=60)
    requisiti= models.TextField(max_length=60)
    nome_azienda= models.CharField(max_length=20, default=' inserisci nome')
    email_referente= models.CharField(max_length=20, default='inserisci email')
```

core/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.views.generic.list import ListView
from .decorators import allowed_user


# Create your views here.
from quiz.models import Questions
from jobs.models import post_job
from functools import wraps



@allowed_user(allowed_roles=['Admin','Students'])
def userProfileView(request, username):
    user= get_object_or_404(User, username=username)
    jobs = post_job.objects.all()
    categories = Questions.CAT_CHOICES
    scores = []
    for category in categories:
        score = Questions.objects.filter(catagory=category[0], student= user).count()
        scores.append(score)

    context = {

    'user' : user, 'categories_scores' : zip( categories,scores),
    'jobs': jobs



    }
    return render(request, 'core/user_profile.html' , context)
```

core/user_profile.html

```
{% extends 'base.html'%}

{% block content %}
<br>
<div class="card-header">
    <h3> {% if request.user == user %} Il tuo {% endif %} Profilo Utente </h3>
    <br>
    <h1> Ciao Studente: @{{ user }}</h1>
</div>

<br>
<br>
{% for category,score in categories_scores %}

<div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
        {{ category.1 }} Score
    </div>

    <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">CONGRATS!</h5>
        <p class="card-text"> Here your SCORE: </p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">{{ score }}</a>
        {% if score > 1 %}
            {% if request.user == user %}
                <br>
                <br>
                <div class="progress">
                    <div class="progress-bar bg-success" role="progressbar" style="width: 99%" aria-valuenow="99" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
                </div>
                <p class="card-text">  Congratulations! Now you can apply to:</p>
                <br>
                {% for job in jobs %}

                    <div id="accordion">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
                                <h5 class="mb-0">
                                    <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                                        {{job.posizione}} <strong> {{job.nome_azienda}} </strong>
                                    </button>
                                </h5>
                            </div>

                            <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordion">
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>    {{job.descrizione}} </li>
                                        <li>    {{job.email_referente}} </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}
        {% else %}
            <br>
            <br>

            <div class="progress">
                <div class="progress-bar bg-warning" role="progressbar" style="width: 25%" aria-valuenow="25" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
            </div>
            <p class="card-text">  Still not meet the requirements to apply, keep going! </p>
        {% endif %}
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>


    {% endfor %}

    {% endblock content %}
```

Comment: Could you remove all code that doesn't directly relate to your issue? There's a few hundred lines here. Most of that html template is likely unneeded, same with all the views unrelated to the question, for example. Try distilling the problem to just its absolute core, to clarify what lines of code are in question here. SO's great at answering questions where there's just a few specific parts of it.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I tried to eliminate some part, hoping I did not delete something important. Basically I think that the problem is on the fact that my post_job Model doesn't "recognize" the CAT_CHOICE in the quiz/models.py. I can't link the job offer to the category of the Questions.

Comment: The question is clearer now, but I think it could be made clearer. I'm still not sure exactly what the issue you're dealing with. Are you going to the UserList view, the profile view or homepage? Removing whichever ones aren't relevant would help. Maybe writing a simple view that has only the code that deals with 'linking the job offer' to help us visualize the issue. I'm assuming the view is `userProfileView`, so maybe if you edited the question further to say like 'I expect `scores` to contain XYZ on line 10' or something.

Comment: Oh, I think I understand the issue, you're saying that `jobs` isn't being filtered by the category with a score, and that logic was being done in the template. So your template was basically doing '`if score_in_category > 1: show(all_jobs)`', but you are looking for `show(jobs_in_this_category)` instead, correct?

Comment: I've rolledback the edit and re-edited the code in the question to only show the bits that are relevant here.

Answer (score 0):

On the line in the template,

```
{% for job in jobs %}
```

You are expecting this to be just the jobs in which the user has scored > 1, but the code never filtered on it, so it's getting all jobs.

One solution could be to add a field on the `post_job` Model for `Question.category`, so that you can filter them down.

Like you said in the comments, there's no connection to between the job and the questions, so that needs to be created.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer! Anyway yes, in my template when I put {% for job in jobs %} it displays the results as in the picture, it shows all the jobs and doesn't filter as I'd like. You got it perfectly. For what I understood, you are suggesting me to import the quiz/models.py in my jobs/models.py and import the Question.category variable, right?

Comment: because the issue I'm having is importing that category variable from quiz.models to jobs.models

Comment: If you mean you're getting an error on importing one file into the other, one option then is it move `Questions.CAT_CHOICES` into its own file without any dependencies, and import that new `category_choices.py` file into both `models.py` files.